# Using case when with subquery when executing insert command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, case-when

I'm looking for how to make an insert command that use case-when syntax that use a subquery inside it. That sounds complicating I know.

I tried google search and made some scripting but still not comeover it for now - I guess the cause is that I'm not familiar with `case-when` command in MySQL as well as embedded subquery for `case-when`.

Please share as you know how.

```
INSERT INTO `someTable` (`someColumn`, `someColumn2`) VALUES
( SUB-QUERY-IN-CASE-WHEN-GOES-HERE, 'someColumnValue'),
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Show some input data and the result you're trying to get from it. There's a number of different ways to do what you're trying, and we need more details to know the right solution.

Comment: How do you know what you are looking for if you are "not familiar with case-when command in MySQL as well as embedded subquery for case-when"?  The best way to ask a question is to provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `someTable` (`someColumn`) 
select case when a = 1
            then 'value1'
            else 'someColumnValue'
       end
from your_table
```

Comment: he wants either `then` or `else` results to be a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this mate:

```
INSERT INTO `someTable` (`someColumn`, `someColumn2`)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN someValue = 1 THEN (
            SELECT
                anotherValue
            FROM
                another_table
            WHERE
                another_condition = 1
        )
        WHEN someValue = 2 THEN (
            SELECT
                anotherValue
            FROM
                another_table
            WHERE
                another_condition = 2
        )
        ELSE (
            SELECT
                anotherValue
            FROM
                another_table
            WHERE
                another_condition = 0
        )
    END 'someColumn',
    'someColumn2'
FROM
    other_table
WHERE
    your_condition = 1;
```

PS:

Nice edit btw, not even a single response to comment/answer. As as much as possible please try to compute/process data on application side, this is not advisable to implement IMHO. Cheers